# Regular Expression and preg_replace PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to replace a string inside a shortcode with an empty string "". This is the code:

```
$pattern = "#\[(.*)( rep=['\"]{1}1['\"]{1})(.*)\]#i";
$replacement = '[$1$3]';

//Test cases:
$values = [
  'This is a [s1 val="1"] test',
  'This is a [s1 val="1"] test rep="1"',
  'This is a [s1 val="1" rep="1"] test',
  'This is a [s1 de="2" rep="1" be="2"] test',
  'This is a [rep="1" de="2" ] test',
  'This is a [s2 val="1" rep="1" de="2"] test ... This is a [s3 val="1" rep="1" de="2" ] test',
];

foreach($values as $value)
{
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $value) . "\n";
}
```

The first five cases work as expected. Unfortunately, the sixth case which has two rep="1" inside doesn't work as expected since I want the rep="1" in both shortcodes removed. This could probably be on the regular expression.

NOTE: the rep="1" must be inside the shortcode (inside the [ and ]) for it to be replaced.

Comment: So you want to replace `rep="1"` value from an array. Try `\[(.*?)(rep="1")(.*?)\]`

Comment: replace rep="1" if it is inside the shortcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the non-greedy quantifier within your regex

```
\[(.*?)(rep="1")(.*?)\]
   //^^          //^^
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/462009)